# ng-style not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need ng-style to set the height of a div inside a resizable div.

This is the controller code that is executed :

```
    $scope.uploadDropStyle = {
        height: $scope.$parent.state.size.window.height - calculateDeduction()
    };


    $scope.$on("window:resize", function (event, width, height) {
        $scope.uploadDropStyle.height = height - calculateDeduction();
    });
```

Here is my link function :

```
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {
            var markup = '<div style="display:table"><form name="fieldEditor" class="entityEditor emailEditor">';
            markup += <div class="fileTransferContainer" ng-style="{{uploadDropStyle}}"><br/><hr/>\
         <few html removed here>
                                </div>\
                           </div>\
                        </div>';
            element.html(markup);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
```

Here is the DOM when I display my div

```
  <div class="fileTransferContainer" style="height: 465px;" ng-style="{&quot;height&quot;:465}">
```

When I resize my window, here is what I get :

```
 <div class="fileTransferContainer" style="height: 465px;" ng-style="{&quot;height&quot;:146}">
```

Why is there this "height: 465px;", and why is my ng-style not applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build you style variable as JSON

```
$scope.uploadDropStyle = {
    "height": $scope.$parent.state.size.window.height - calculateDeduction() + "px"
};
```

I would extend my answer with recommending you to use a scope variable into the ng-style tag instead of a binded one:

```
markup += <div class="fileTransferContainer" ng-style="uploadDropStyle"><br/><hr/>\
```

Comment: I had found another solution : "{\'height\' : (uploadDropStyle.height) + \'px\'}"
But yours is better

Comment: Great @DeblatonJean-Philippe